# Python tkinter creating rectangle error

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to create a rectangle on a tkinter canvas the line of code I am using is this: `c.create_rectangle(x, y, x2, y2, fill=fill_, outline=outline_)`. The variables are all defined c being the canvas variable and the rest numbers and colour names when I run the code the following error occurs: invalid command name ".130125072" (This number is random) and bearing in mind that all of the arguments I have given are integers I have no idea why this error is occurring. If you could give me the answer to why this is not working I will be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give specific values for your variables, so we can replicate the issue.

Comment: Ok for example: x=10, y=10, x2=20, y2=20, fill="red", outline="red"

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. The error mostly likely means you are trying to create a rectangle on a canvas that has been deleted. ".130125072" isn't a number, is the internal name of a widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How tkinter works:

- `create_rectangle` adds a rectangle, but doesn't draw it
- it returns an id (the number), so you can modify it later
- when you call `mainloop` everything displays

---

this will get you a rectangle

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, mainloop
c = Canvas(Tk(), width=200, height=100)
c.pack()

c.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="red", outline="red")

mainloop()
```

---

If you want to use tkinter from the command line, there's discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spyderlib/FApxLSELrQY) about how to configure it but it looks complicated.